# Are torpedo 3 gear shift cables a standard or are there different sizes?

Tags: internally-geared-hub

I want to replace the cable of a bike with an old sachs torpedo 3 gears internal hub and I'm not sure what do I have to buy.

In [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14275/sachs-torpedo-3-gear-vs-sram-t3-vs-sram-i-motion-3-gear) related question the answer is that there are some differences between latter sram hubs, but, is the cable the same?

When I search some for that cable in some shops they only write that it is for torpedo/sram but anything about different models.

Mine look like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you slide the cable out of the shifter so the end is visible? If it has a standard end, there are universal 3 speed cables. The threaded fitting is attached and adjusted with a pinch bolt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the normal shift cables (and housing) work fine, but there is a special end cap on the cable that fits into this hollow rod-like thing in the lower left corner of the picture. Normal cable end caps do not fit into this, because they are too thick. The original part made is out of brass and squeezed on with pliers. It's the center piece in this picture:
[image: Brass end cap]
You can also find some hollow brass rod in a model train shop or similar and clip off a small piece. It just has to fit inside the rod.